# Batch conversion with write.xlsx and header name issue

Tags: r, formatting, xlsx

I am batch converting a lot of .csv files to xlsx format using `write.xlsx` in the `openxlsx` package
I use the following to convert the list of files (there are over 200).
The reason I need to do this is for upload to a database, it will only accept xlsx files.

```
filenames <- list.files("C:/split files", pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)

for(i in filenames) {
  a <- read.csv(i)
  new_name <- sub('.csv', '.xlsx', i, fixed = TRUE)
  write.xlsx(a, new_name, row.names = F)
```

The problem I have is that the headers which used to have spaces in their names (again required format for the database) now have "." where the spaces used to be. Is there a simple way to add to the above code and replace the "." with " " ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
read.csv(i, check.names = F)
```

You got that "." because R checks and converts your column names when reading the csv file. We can preserve original names by disabling that checking.